# How to check assert empty string in python unittest?

Tags: python-2.7, python-unittest

I have a question that I would like to test a given empty string `msg = ''` in python unittest but I could not found the right assertion function for it.

I have tried with:

```
self.assertIsNone(msg)
```

But I got an error

```
AssertionError: '' is not None
```

So I went on with

```
self.assertIsEmpty(msg)
```

But I got

```
object has no attribute 'assertIsEmpty'
```

Therefore, what is the correct way to check an empty string in unittest? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for

```
assertEqual(x, '')
```

[Documentation for Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#assert-methods)

[Documentation for Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#assert-methods)

Comment: thanks very much, I just thought it has a specific function for checking empty string.

Comment: It's true that some kind of `assertIsBlank` or `assertIsEmptyString` does appear in many testing frameworks, but Python's `unittest`, being built in, is fairly lightweight in this area. Many of the assertions were actually added in Python 2.7. :)